# Is public void Execute(string sql) considered dangerous?

Tags: t-sql

Is it considered dangerous if I implement a method like this in my assembly?

```
 public void Execute(string sql)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString....."))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();                
            }
        }
```

Comment: It depends on where that string is coming from and how it is created.

Answer (score 1):

It is *dangerous* if the sql string you are passing in is being dynamically built and includes the concatenation of user input.  Otherwise it is generally considered bad practice.  Stored procedures are your best bet.

[Here is the OWASP article on SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

Comment: I am more concerned about consumer class passing in a sql like "DROP TABLE Employees". Is this a legitimate concern?

Comment: Absolutely.  Passing parameters to stored procedures will mitigate the risk because the data inside of parameters can never be executed against the database.

Comment: I don't have parameters to pass in.  I need to drop and create a table using C#. Should I simply validate the table name before I execute the sql?  Or maybe I should have a DropTable method and a CreateTable method that takes 0 arguments? Less flexible, more duplicated code, but more secure?  What do you think?

Comment: Yours is a special case if you are expecting people to be sending in requests to drop tables.  Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, see my comment to Matt Whipple.